# Facebook SDK Can't Fetch Email Address

Tags: facebook, sdk

I'm trying to fetch user details by signing  to facebook. I am able to get FACEBOOK ID and Profile Pic which shows up fine  but not Email Address and Name for some reason I can't figure. Below is the code that I am using.

Facebook App and Oath are properly configured. Pls see what is wrong in below code.

```
<?php

define('APP_ID', 'xxxxxx');
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxx');
define('REDIRECT_URL','callback.php');
session_start();


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Login </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body{
            width:100%;
            margin:0;
        }
        .facebooklogin{
            font-size:100%;
            font-family:arial;
            display:block;
            width:200px;
            height:20px;
            background-color:#142dac;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:20px;
            border-radius:5px;
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .facebooklogin:hover{
            background-color:#4158cc;
        }

        .user{
            font-size:100%;
            font-family:arial;
            display:block;
            width:100%;
            background-color:#142dac;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
            border-radius:5px;
        }

        .wrapper{
            width:60%;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding:20px;
        }



            .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; width:100%;}
            .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
            .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<?php



//INCLUDING LIBRARIES 
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

//USING NAMESPACES
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;

//STARTING SESSION



FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(APP_ID,APP_SECRET);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(REDIRECT_URL);

$sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();


if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
}

$logout = 'http://localhost/FacebookLoginPHP?logout=true';

if(isset($sess)){
    $_SESSION['token']=$sess->getToken();

    $request  = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    $name = $graph->getName();
    $id = $graph->getId();
    $img = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=300';
    $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
    $birthday = $graph->getProperty('birthday');
    $sex = $graph->getProperty('gender');
?>  
    <div class='user'>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <table class="tg">
              <tr>
                <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="5"><img src='<?php echo $img;?>' /></th>
                <th class="tg-031e" ><?php  ?></th>
                <th class="tg-031e"><?php  echo $name; ?></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">User ID</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Email</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $email; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Gender</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $sex; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">Date of Birth</td>
                <td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $birthday; ?></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <a class="facebooklogin" href='<?php echo $logout; ?>'>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Logout
    </a>

<?php
}else{
?>
    <a class="facebooklogin" href='<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_birthday'));?>'>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
    </a>
<?php
}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: please clear a bit more

Comment: NAME : XYZ
 
    User ID :101530790518528

    Email:  

Gender 

    Date of Birth


This is the output I get, Email, Gender DOB are blank

Comment: You have to ask for the email field to get email